# How do i make a switch statement more efficient?

Tags: java

I'm in the scenario where i need to put a lot of cases for increments of integers. I was wondering how can i make this more efficient and easier to read?
Here's the code:

```
public static void volumeControl() {
    int selection;
    System.out.println("Volume. 1-10");
    selection = input.nextInt();
    switch (selection) {
        case 1: volume = -10;
            break;
        case 2: volume = -8;
            break;
        case 3: volume = -6;
            break;
        case 4: volume = -4;
            break;
        case 5: volume = -2;
            break;
        case 6: volume = 0;
            break;
        case 7: volume = 2;
            break;
        case 8: volume = 4;
            break;
        case 9: volume = 5;
            break;
        case 10: volume = 6;
            break;
    }
```

I can't add them because the variable "volume" is a float!

Comment: is switch working?

Comment: In Java you can type cast to another type, which might solve your issue if you are okay with less granularity in the volume.

Comment: If you changed case 9 to 6 and case 10 to 8 it'd be straightforward to calculate the volume based on the selection.

Comment: It's already efficient enough but an array lookup would be easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 7):

You could declare and initialize an array as a member of your class, containing the volume values, then simply use the selection entered as an index into the array:

```
float[10] volumeLookup = { -10, -8, ... };
...
volume = volumeLookup[ selection - 1 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` in this case. They are basically used to map `key`s to `values`. In this case, your your input will act as an integer key that will map to a specific float value.

```
public static void volumeControl() {
    Map<Integer, Float> volume = new HashMap<>();
    volume.put(1, -10f);
    volume.put(2, -8f);
    volume.put(3, -6f);
    volume.put(4, -4f);
    volume.put(5, -2f);
    volume.put(6, 0f);
    volume.put(7, 2f);
    volume.put(8, 4f);
    volume.put(9, 5f);
    volume.put(10, 6f);

    int selection;
    System.out.println("Volume. 1-10");
    selection = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("volume: " + volume.get(selection));
}
```

Comment: Still lots of code duplicated due to calling `put`.

Comment: I understand. I think if only these set of inputs which OP have provided in question are there, then it's better to use @Dave Costa's solution. But, as OP said, if there are lots and lots of integer **with random patterns**, then it's better to use Map's as because that's what they are for. Moreover, If the sole purpose is to reduce the lines of code, then you can use that array, but I think that doesn't solve the readability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switch, it would save you space by making the numbers you inputted into an array, so that way, it would save all the numbers at once.

Answer (score 0):

Just to enhance rD's answer,

```
  Map<int, float> volume = new HashMap<>();
    volume.put(1, -10f);
    volume.put(2, -8f);
    volume.put(3, -6f);
    volume.put(4, -4f);
    volume.put(5, -2f);
    volume.put(6, 0f);
    volume.put(7, 2f);
    volume.put(8, 4f);
    volume.put(9, 5f);
    volume.put(10, 6f);


public static void volumeControl(int selected) {
  // Get the volume
  // Notice I did not perform validation checks, if you have to please do it here.
  volume.get(selected);

  // Do whatever you need to set the volume
}
```

If its possible, initialize the map somewhere else, doing it again and again the method is going to drag your performance.